# 404 on Azure Functions GET Request

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

The following file is absolutely right, I double checked it. The name matches the Azure website, the API Key is in there, why am I getting no response at all when trying to use this on Postman as a GET?

```
//https://disney-clone-portfolio.azurewebsites.net/api/getaisuggestion?term=action

import {
  app,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponseInit,
  InvocationContext,
} from "@azure/functions";

import OpenAI from "openai";

const openAI = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export async function getAISuggestion(
  request: HttpRequest,
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

  const term = request.query.get("term");

  const completion = await openAI.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: `You are a digital video assistant working for services such as Netflix, Disney Plus & Amazon Prime Video. Your job is to provide suggestions based on the videos the user specifies. Provide an quirky breakdown of what the user should watch next! It should only list the names of the films after the introduction. Keep the response short and sweet! Always list at least 3 films as suggestions. If the user mentions a genre, you should provide a suggestion based on that genre.`,
      },
      {
        role: "user",
        content: `I like: ${term}`,
      },
    ],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
  });

  return {
    body: completion.choices[0].message.content || "No suggestions found",
  };
}

app.http("getAISuggestion", {
  methods: ["GET"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: getAISuggestion,
});
```

Comment: Is the function configured to be publically accessible? How did you deploy the function?

Comment: yes! See here, it's the URL that's commented out https://prnt.sc/aV0UV7xJzhG7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to execute the function locally before deploying to the function app to ensure that the function is not throwing any error and works as expected.
- I have modified the code to use Azure OpenAI.

```js
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const apiVersion = '2024-02-15-preview';
const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;

const openAI = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: apiKey,
  baseURL: process.env.OPENAI_BASE_URL,
  defaultQuery: { 'api-version': apiVersion },
  defaultHeaders: { 'api-key': apiKey },
});


export async function getAISuggestion(
    request: HttpRequest,
    context: InvocationContext
    ): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

    const term = request.query.get("term");

    const completion = await openAI.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      {
        role: 'user',
        content: `You are a digital video assistant working for services such as Netflix, Disney Plus & Amazon Prime Video. Your job is to provide suggestions based on the videos the user specifies. Provide an quirky breakdown of what the user should watch next! It should only list the names of the films after the introduction. Keep the response short and sweet! Always list at least 3 films as suggestions. If the user mentions a genre, you should provide a suggestion based on that genre.`,
      },
      {
        role: "user",
        content: `I like: ${term}`,
      },
    ],
    model: "gpt-35-turbo-16k",
  });

  return {
    body: completion.choices[0].message.content || "No suggestions found",
  };
};

app.http('getAISuggestion', {
    methods: ['GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: getAISuggestion
});
```

- Added API key and base URL in local settings file.

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "OPENAI_API_KEY": "a0ee****2a3",
    "OPENAI_BASE_URL": "https://{resource_name}.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{model}"
  }
}
```

- I am getting expected output locally.

[image]

[image]

- I deployed the function to the function app using vs code or you can use *`func azure functionapp publish {func-app-name}`* command too.

[image]

- Added the key and base url in ***App Settings*** post deployment.

[image]

- I am able to invoke the function URL successfully.

[image]

Comment: I did another one using OpenAI a bit differently, I didn't use functions at all, but it worked fine as well. The point here is when using without that OpenAI URL, like for me it's the one that is commented out. See my Microsoft Azure here https://prnt.sc/aV0UV7xJzhG7.  Just to clarify, how did you run the function locally?

Comment: @Caio In your screenshot, it shows the function app url not the function url. I executed my function in browser as we as in postman locally. I can't see any function in the function tab of overview blade in your screenshot. Have you deployed your function correctly? You should be able to see the function in functions tab

Comment: That's what I'm checking right now. Inside my VSCode using the Azure Functions extension, I run Deploy to Function App, it shows me this https://prnt.sc/ihy7a2Xf7ZtY but it seems that the function never gets there... I have no idea why, I select the correct function app and there's a function inside my project like this https://prnt.sc/I8bZZTuL76D4

Comment: The outout is here, sorry https://prnt.sc/ItctjGPZoruu

Comment: @Caio so after deployment, trigger is not syncing that's why you are not able to see the function. Check in your app settings if you have AzureWebJobFeatureFlags added as shown in my screenshot

Comment: If not present add `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableWorkerIndexing` and then deploy. Post deployment, you should be able to see the endpoint of your function in the output tab in vs code

Comment: That is already present, check here https://prnt.sc/TCCIIietAJy4

Comment: @Caio Add it in function app before deployment if not present. To add navigation to function app -> environment variables and then add the key and values in the app settings. I also have added a screenshot in my answer, please check. When we deploy a function to function app then local settings file doesn't get deploy with it, it is only for local development.

Comment: @Caio in your case add the given values in the function app -> configuration as Azure portal not updated yet so you might not see environment variables in function app. So add it in `Configuration` blade of function app

Comment: inside VSCode I did Upload Local Settings, so they're syncronized, as you can see here https://prnt.sc/Vf8lY4ZrwlXw. And your screenshot didn't come!

Comment: and indeed, I couldn't find a environment variables option

Comment: Ok it seems you have added it. Can you deploy now

Comment: no HTTP triggers still: https://prnt.sc/kWaUXfHvdgZj https://prnt.sc/sbNYjdAwbFsE https://prnt.sc/4qI7BRPUW9GT

Comment: Can you share your function code screenshot here meanwhile try to publish with this command `func azure functionapp publish {func-app-name}`

Comment: func will not exist for me as a command, should I install the Azure Tools or something? My function https://prnt.sc/q0YA-xsP1nye

Comment: Full command `1. az login
2. az account set --subscription "Subscription name"
3. func azure functionapp publish functionappname`

Comment: Try to restart the function app once before deploying

Comment: @Caio are you able to get the output locally?

Comment: I'm getting to it, just have to install Functions Core Tools, hang on

Comment: okay, now this is weird https://prnt.sc/wy-50BIPUAhh https://prnt.sc/S8dgdvo_VIQ0

Comment: okay, update: I got this: https://prnt.sc/QDDJ1Lu_9fHK postman gives me this https://prnt.sc/1GRmdfXHeRpA

Comment: @Caio were you able to get the output locally? Your function deployed successfully but I believe you need to check if your function runs locally if yes then it should work in function app as well

Comment: not really, which command did you use to deploy it locally?

Comment: To run locally either run your project on debug mode or click on fn + f5 or use `func host start` in terminal

Comment: Isn't this free? https://prnt.sc/3LHH2kN_x3n6

Comment: @Caio Nope, it's not free. In my case I have created an Azure OpenAI instance and then used it's credentials like baseurl and key

Comment: I guess we found my problem, haven't we? haha

Comment: @Caio Yes, I guess this might be the reason you are not getting output in function app

Comment: thank you so so much for your disposition!